# In LinqPad, is there a way to serialize type XML column as string?

Tags: linqpad

I have a XML column on SQL. And there are malformed data exist in it. Which causes the error **"There are multiple root elements."** when I run `MyTable.Take(4).Dump();`

*e.g.*

```
<cy>
  <n>NameA</n>
  <p>true</p>
</cy>
<cy>
  <n>NameB</n>
  <p>false</p>
</cy>
```

Is there a way to tell LinQPad to not serialize XML column and provide it as a string?

> *Unfortunately data is tied up with many places so I can not wrap it with root element on database right away.*

Comment: interestingly, when I try `MyTable.Take(4).Dump();`, I get the same error as you, but doing `MyTable.Take(4).Select(row => row.XmlColumnName.ToString()).Dump();` it works. So I guess the answer is project the column to a string that way?

Comment: It is definitely a workaround and I appreciate that.  However I would like to keep question open, in-case @joe-albahari may provide a property based serialization method like he did on exclude property options.  Thanks again

Comment: have you seen http://www.linqpad.net/CustomizingDump.aspx? :)

Comment: I was talking about it when I mention `exclude` method. :) Great catch! Unfortunately error thrown before `.Dump()` at `.Take(4)`. I need to be able to interact with `LINQPad.User.*` queries at initial serialization level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest [LINQPad beta](http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx#beta), version 5.10.06, allows you to access the XML columns as strings:

> ## NEW/IMPROVED:
>
> There's a new checkbox in the SQL advanced connection properties dialog to map XML columns to .NET `string`s instead of `XElement`s. This allows you to query tables with malformed XML without error.