# Is it possible to change LINQPad code generation on XML type?

Tags: linq-to-sql, code-generation, linqpad

In SQL Server a table can have a XML column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [C1] [xml] NULL
)
```

XML column allows multiple root content, it's legal to put below into xml column

```
<a>1</a><a>2</a>
```

When doing query, I got this error,

```
There are multiple root elements
```

[image]

I think the cause of the error is CLR data type LINQPad/Linq-to-SQL auto-generated.

```
public XElement C1;
```

XElement does not allow multiple root content.

Is it possible to intervene the code generation process, so change the data type as string?

```
public String C1;
```

btw, the assembly LinqPad generated is at

[image]

Comment: You can use VS to generate a typed `DataContext` and have LINQPad use it instead of the automatically generated one.

Comment: Also, you can change the connection properties as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40508363/2557128).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the advanced properties on the SQL Connection dialog to map XML columns to string.

[image]